Aligning text, image and list vertically in beamer slide
I am trying to aligne text image and an itemize list, but I want the list to be left align with regard to the image. Something like this:


\documentclass{beamer}

\begin{document}

\begin{frame}{a frame}
    a small paragraph that introduce something crucial
    \begin{columns}
        \column{.4\textwidth}

        \begin{figure}[t]
            \centering
            \includegraphics[width=.8\textwidth]{images/fake.png}
        \end{figure}

        \small
        \vfill
        \textbf{a few more words}
        \begin{itemize}
                \tiny
            \item one element
            \item another one element
            \item ont that will be even larger
        \end{itemize}
    \end{columns}
\end{frame}


\end{document}

This almost work, using a one column columns environment, but I would like "a few more words" to be centered and this isn't robust if I change image size, etc... if I use \centering then the problem is that the itemize list is centered and make a pyramid like below, and I would it to stayt aligned with the left part of the image above...
If anyone has any idea on how to do it!


I suggest to make the image as wide as the column/minipage/whatever and then use
\settowidth{\leftmargini}{\usebeamertemplate{itemize item}}
\addtolength{\leftmargini}{\labelsep}

to align the bullet points with the edge of the environment:

\documentclass{beamer}

\begin{document}

\begin{frame}
\frametitle{a frame}
    a small paragraph that introduce something crucial
    \centering
    
    \begin{minipage}[t][.6\textheight]{.4\textwidth}
       \centering
       \vfill
       \includegraphics[width=\textwidth]{example-image-duck}
        \small
        \vfill
        \textbf{a few more words}
        
        \settowidth{\leftmargini}{\usebeamertemplate{itemize item}}
        \addtolength{\leftmargini}{\labelsep}
        \begin{itemize}
            \tiny
            \item one element
            \item another one element
            \item ont that will be even larger
        \end{itemize}
    \end{minipage}
\end{frame}


\end{document}



thanks you very much! that's exactly what I needed. minipage is really an environment I should think about more often. And thanks also for the duck image, didn't know we had access to these :D

@SimonC. You're welcome! I thought the duck image would be more fun than /images/fake.png :)
